# How to move a GameObject for using a Vector2 in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that I want to move in Unity. I want to move it by a fixed distance. I have tried using AddForce but the game object keeps on moving infinitely.

Here is my code:

```
Vector2 movementMonster = new Vector2(-4, 0);
rbMonster1.AddForce(movementMonster);
```

I have also tried Translate without any results:

```
monster1.transform.Translate(Vector2.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

.Translate requires a Vector3:

```
Vector3 movementMonster = new Vector3(-4, 0, 0);
```

Do you want to move it a fixed distance in a single frame?

```
monster1.transform.Translate(movementMonster);
```

or over a certain time (for example a second)?

```
monster1.transform.Translate(movementMonster * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: it moves the object but it never stops. It keeps on moving until it falls from the scene. I want it to stop after it reached a certain position in the scene.

Comment: this is the code to move the object, if you want it to stop then stop calling this code

Answer (score 1):

The Transform.Translate(movementMonster) will move your GameObject by the defined Vector3 movement monster every time you call it. 
Example:

Let's assume that start position of the monster if Vector3(0,0)

```
monster1.transform.Translate(movementMonster);
```

After first call your monster is now at Vector3(-4, 0, 0)

```
monster1.transform.Translate(movementMonster);
```

After first call your monster is now at Vector3(-8, 0, 0)

```
monster1.transform.Translate(movementMonster);
```

Vector3(-12, 0, 0) etc..

As long as I understand you need to move the 'monster' to certain position over time. You can use the method of `Vector3.MoveTowards()` so you can skip some math.

```
using UnityEngine;

class Monster : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 endPosition;
    public float speed = 1f; // The monster will move a one unity per second
        public void Update(){
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPosition, step);
    }
```

You may want to hit the Unity3D tutorial page, where this kind of basics are explained.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting